# d3.js Axis component keeps invisible ticks (cause memory leak)

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to create a sliding time series. It's will be used in a dashboard widget, that will track *something* for the last minute.

Nothing more than the X axis component. It's just to test this feature.

Here is the code :

```
 var now = parseInt(Date.now() / 1000) * 1000;// rounded to second
 var t = 60;
 data = d3.range(60).map(init); // init last minute

 function init() {
     t = t - 1;
     return {
         time: now - t * 1000,
         value: 0
     };
 }

 setInterval(function () {
     data.shift();
     data.push({
         time: parseInt(Date.now() / 1000) * 1000,
         value: Math.random() * 200
     });
     redraw();
 }, 1000);

 var margin = { top: 20, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 50 };
 var width = 800 - margin.left - margin.right;
 var height = 300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

 var x = d3.time.scale()
  .domain([now - 60 * 1000, now])
  .range([0, width]);

 var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
 .orient("bottom").ticks(d3.time.second, 5);

 var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .attr("class", "chart")
     .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
     .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
     .append("g")
     .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

 svg.selectAll("rect")
     .data(data);

 //xaxis
 var axis = svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "x axis")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
                    .call(xAxis);

 function redraw() {

     now = parseInt(Date.now() / 1000) * 1000;
     x.domain([now - 60 * 1000, now]);

     axis.transition()
     .duration(1000)
     .ease("linear")
 .call(xAxis);
 }
```

Event if not perfect, it works quite well but I there is possible memory issue that is pertinent for a dashboard component.

Some ticks are persisted in the svg, even if there are no longer visible.
After a few minutes, we can see extra groups/ticks.

[image: example]

The fiddle is available [here](http://jsfiddle.net/X2KBB/).

What is wrong in my code ? Did I misunderstood something ?

Thanks,

Comment: The axis code explicitly removes ticks that are no longer generated by the scale. You could print `x.ticks()` inside `redraw()` to verify that the correct ticks are generated.

Comment: you're true : the first tick (the oldes timestamp) is correct. But what about the extras svg elements ? Why are they still in the document ?

Comment: They should be removed by the same transition that updates the axis. What version of D3 are you using?

Comment: Hmmm, it looks like the transitions may be interfering with each other. It works for me without problems if I set the transition duration to 0. Also with a small offset (e.g. duration 950) it seems to work fine and I don't notice a difference in terms of the smoothness of the animation.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. seems to work fine for me too. However, even if I have a workaround, this does not completely solve my initial scenario

Comment: The way to synchronise this properly would be to set the new data after the transition has finished, i.e. with the `.each("end", function())` event. This is fired for each element though, so you would need something to figure out whether to actually update the data.